# How do I define a RAILS Api in routes.rb for get request along with the already existing index method for a get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I already have a method named index and is defined in routes.rb to return the data from the table. The record table contains file names, and I need to expose another API with a get request, to return the file contents of the last added file.

This is how I define it right now:

```
resources :diet_charts, only: [] do
          collection do
            get :index
            get :index_jsonchart
          end
        end
```

'/diet_charts' returns the needed records from the table, but '/diet_charts/index_jsonchart' throws exception saying:
'No route matches [GET] "diet_charts/index_jsonchart"'

How do I define it in routes.rb so that it is accessible from outside along with index?

Comment: I just added your code and I am able to get /diet_charts/index_jsonchart, could you push your code on github, so that I can take a closer look

Comment: Thanks for your time. But some magic happened. I removed the '_' from api and route thereof, and it started working. Not sure why was it giving pain. The URL shared was not the exact URL, rather the trailing part of a long url.
Thread closed.

Comment: Closed thread. Issue was resolved.